DC motor MOSFET driver (with flyback diode) keeps burning through
I am trying to build a (simple) DC motor MOSFET driver with an unknown specification of the motor.
This is my schematic:

The problem is that the circuit works for one, maybe two cycles (1 cycle = 1 shot in an airsoft gun, takes around 200 milliseconds,) then it burns through and keeps spinning the motor.
I don’t know the inductance of the motor, but the DC resistance. I also don’t have the equipment to measure the peak current of more than 10 A when switching the motor on. Since I power this thing with a 2s Lipo (7.4 V; 1200 mAh; 20 C) the burst current should be less than 24 A.
I have two theories why it does not work but I don't really know which one is true. Maybe it is something else.
Since I have only one MOSFET left, I hope I can make this one work.

Since the R_DS(on) of the MOSFET is specified at V_GS 10 V and I only operate it at 7.4 V, the resistance of the MOSFET is higher than specified and it gets too hot. I tried to measure the R_DS(on) myself for different V_GS but I am not sure whether I did it right. My conclusion was, that above 1.8 V there is not much of a change regarding the resistance.

The flyback diode might be switching too slow, since the constant forward current of it is at 20 A (but peak up to 275A.) The MOSFET can take 202 A constantly, so maybe the reverse current when switching off the motor still goes over the MOSFET and kills it.



Yeah so there's a few things here. First up, your mosfet turns off WAY too slow for something you are trying to do high current with.
Switching speed has to do directly with the gate resistor used to power the gate of the mosfet. Since you are doing high current (which, for this example I define as more than ~2-3 amps), you need to keep switching times to a minimum. When a MOSFET is powered on, it has to travel through a linear region where its resistance is really high, but still conducts current. This is where most of the power loss occurs if switching is slow.
I will state now that buying a gate driver is pretty much always the best option.
If you still don't want to do that, you can improve your circuit above. A diode has an 0.7 V drop on it, so if you find your diode getting hot, that is because 24 A * 0.7 V = 16.8 W. If it's not getting hot, that's likely because its not being held at 24 A for very long. You may find that in high frequency applications (dependent on inductor size/current), your diode may get hot. If it doesn't here, it's likely not a big deal.
Now to fix the gate drive section. It has a gate charge of about 90 nanoCoulombs at 6.7 Volts (you will see why I chose 6.7 in a second). I = C dv/dt for a capacitor, and if you want to go from 0 V to 6.7V in 1 microsecond (we really don't want this mosfet to stay on for long), we can look at the datasheet for this capacitor and see that the input Capacitance is about 6000 picofarads (or 6 nanofarads). We can then plug this into our equation above, and get that our current should be about 40.2mA. Your 100 ohm resistor actually services us just fine here as it provides about 67mA at 6.7 V, which means it turns on pretty fast.
BUT, the pull-down resistor is the thing we don't like here, as it is 27 kilo-ohms. 6.7 V / 27 kilo-ohms is 200 micro-amps, which is FAR too slow and will likely fry your transistor from staying too long in the linear region when running 10+ amps.
I suggest a schematic like this:

Source: me
Here we use a class B amplifier (an NPN transistor on top of a PNP) to take our input signal of HIGH or LOW via the switch that's labeled U1, and amplify the current by multiple orders of magnitude so we have a high current output. This is where the 6.7 Volts comes into play. Class B amplifiers drop the voltage range of your supply by 1.4 V, 0.7 V on both end. So our 7.4 V supply gets dropped to 6.7 V, and our 0 V becomes 0.7 V on the output. Given that the mosfet is still "on" at 6.7 V and "off" at 0.7 V, this shouldn't be a massive issue. However, your switching speed is still about 10x faster on turn on and about 200x faster on turn off.
Note: I didn't have your mosfet in my LTSpice library, but I had a similarly spec'd one so I used that instead.
As far as MOSFET failure modes go, most of the times when mosfets die, they fail short, which means the entire thing is short circuited to itself. You likely aren't overvolting the transistor unless your diode is incredibly slow (like you said). If you overheat a transistor, it can fail as well, and from my experience it typically fails short. A way to tell whether or not you are overheating it is by using the temperature stats on the datasheet.
If you don't have a heatsink on your mosfet, look at the R_{theta}JA parameter in the datasheet, which stands for Thermal Resistance from Junction to Ambient. This is roughly the amount of degrees celcius that the transistor temperature rises when 1 Watt of heat is dissipated in it, with no heatsink. In your case, it is 62 degrees C increased per every 1 Watt dissipated. The resistance of the mosfet is 4 milliohms, and the current we have is 7.4/0.5 = 14.8 Amps. P = I^2 * R, which in your case is about 0.87 Watts. 0.87 watts is well within the operating range of this mosfet which can function up to 175 degrees Celcius, so clearly we must be getting extra heat from the slow turn-off time of this mosfet.
If you have any other questions about gate drivers, see this stackexchange post I answered a few weeks ago considerably more in depth than I did here, and this video from Sam Ben-Yaakov that is a full lecture on the functions of a gate driver.

Thanks for the in-depth answer, it will take me some time to figure out everthing that you said. Some questions might be following! :)

I expect your diode isn't fast enough.  Brushed DC motors throw out some really fast transients when running and when switched off.
You need the reverse recovery time of the diode to be fast enough that the voltage spikes from the commutator don't have time to rise before the diode switches on to clamp them.
The datasheet of your 2SQ045 Schottky diode doesn't mention the switching speed at all.  It is intended for use in putting solar panels in parallel.  That usage needs a low voltage drop at high current, not fast switching speeds.
You need a fast diode that can handle the peak current of your motor.
That'll be something rated for fast switching that can also handle high speed. A UF 5402 might do the trick.  Its reverse recovery time is 50 nanoseconds.  It can handle 3A continuous with peaks to 175A.  The 5402 is rated for 200V peak inverse voltage.
That will probably be an improvement over what you are using, but might not cover it all.
Look into adding a snubber made of a resistor and a capacitor.  The snubber will slow the rise time of the spikes so that the diode can catch them before they rise too high.
AN280 from STMicroelectronics goes into some detail on calculating the snubber resistor and capacitor values.  You need to figure out how much voltage rise you can allow (difference between power supply voltage and the MOSFET rated voltage minus a safety factor) and you need the rise time you want to allow (50 nanoseconds if using the UF5402.)  I fudged my way through to a working circuit for a hobby project, but I don't think I'm the right person to tell you how to do the calculations.

Thanks for your answer and your suggestion for another diode. I think I will try to use this one for an easy fix.
Do you know how high the rated voltage of the snubber capacitor should be?
I heard the flyback voltage can be estimated by V_cc * 10; but I don’t know if thats right..

The capacitor needs to have a higher voltage rating than the maximum voltage rise you want to allow.

since i cant really measure the peak voltage, i have to estimate. Is this Rule of thumb (V_CC*10) accurate enough?

It is not useful.  You don't need to account for a crazy high voltage.  You need to keep the peak below 40 V because that's all the MOSFET can stand.  Your circuit is operating on 7.4V, so 20V would be a good limit.  The snubber capacitor and its resistors only need to slow the rise for maybe 100 nanoseconds until the diode kicks in.  When the diode kicks in, the voltage will be limited to the battery voltage plus the diode forward voltage.  Call it 14V.  Since the snubber and the diode limit the voltage, you don't need a crazy high rating on the capacitor.

A capacitor rated for the same voltage as the MOSFET should do.  A typical voltage rating for a capacitor would be 50VDC.

Thanks! I know have (hopefully) last questions about the capacitor choice: I would choose something like a ceramic capacitor. Definitely something that does not have a polarity (because I would apply reverse voltage while driving the motor, right?). Don’t want it to do the magic smoke trick ;)
For the capacity value I would choose something not too great. Theory tells me that it takes approx R*C *5 seconds to charge the capacitor 99%. I would aim this to be ~100ns.
